# How to set a value for slider if its position is 2 or 3 or 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery slider.Is it possible to set a value for slide basing on its position.

Ex:

min    (1   2    3    4    5 ) Max

value('100' '150' '200' '400' '500')

if the slider is at position 3, it should show the value 200 in the label.

Thank you.

Comment: No one never understand what you want , which you have posted here. try to be more specific with some code if possible.

Comment: Before posting a question read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: In the Drop down List Box, if we select any item we can get its value (by SelectedValue) im trying the same with slider.. If the slider is at position 3 then it should display its value 200 in the label. This is my question

Comment: What's wrong with question voting? The question is not bad.

Comment: For example, what is slide? There's no such HTML tag nor it is standart javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is jquery ui

```
$("#sliderId").slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 150,
                min: 1,
                step:100,
                max: 500,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {

                    if(ui.value == 1)
                         $("#textBoxId").val( 100 );
                    else if(ui.value == 2)
                         $("#textBoxId").val( 150 );
                    else if(ui.value == 3)
                         $("#textBoxId").val( 200 );
                    else if(ui.value == 4)
                         $("#textBoxId").val( 300 );
                    else if(ui.value == 5)
                         $("#textBoxId").val( 4100 );
                }
    });
```